# PyAudio : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PyAudio'

Tags: python, audio-recording, pyaudio

Today I installed Pyaudio by using instruction on http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/
and trying to run some examples like this one.

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
            channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

and when I'm trying to run it

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PyAudio'
```

How can this be?

Comment: You might use some outdated pyaudio version. Since you didn't provide the version it's hard to give you more detailed answer.

Comment: I use the latest version on http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

and it's 0.2.8

Comment: If you do a `for name in vars(pyaudio): print name` it will show you everything in the imported module. If `PyAudio` isn't shown, then it sounds ;-) like there was a module installation issue.

Comment: why do you need the version when he has already said he installed it "today"

Comment: @Denis that isn't a guarantee that he installed a recent version. A requirements file could have an old version specified.

Answer (score 4):

Did you name your example file `pyaudio.py`? When I did, I got the same error. In this case just rename your working file.

Comment: please add a complete example for the solution. What name should the file have afterwards to work again?

Comment: This method worked for me. I renamed the script to something else other than pyaudio.py

Comment: For imports, python looks in your working directory first. This means if you have any `script.py` with the name of a module you want to use in the directory your program won't work. As the answer says, this includes the current file

Answer (score 1):

Your version of python may not be compatible with pyaudio(i.e pyaudio is not available on python 3).
If you want to install pyaudio on python 3 using pip open this link. 
NOTE: 
 This is for windows os only

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

Click on the version you want to download

for tutorials on the installation use this link: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-AzGZ_CHzJk
start watching from 3min
Pyaudio should when you are done with this

Answer (score 0):

I have never used PyAudio, but I have used SpeechRecogition, and in that, you may have to use PortAudio, based off of operating system.
Download [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)(brew) first.

## Debian Linux

`$ brew install portaudio`
`$ pip install pyaudio`

## MacOS

`$ brew install portaudio`
`$ pip install pyaudio`

If a windows user, then I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try typing in terminal

```
pip install pyaudio
```

Comment: This is not the error that would be produced if pyaudio weren't installed.

Answer (score 0):

pyaudio is difficult to install on some platforms.  On linux it fails because it wants a different compiler.  Anacoda will install a compiled wheel; so you can do a conda install pyaudio.  You can also do a sudo apt install python-pyaudio.  I don't know about windows or mac.